# Excel formatting

Tags: excel, text, formatting

I have a spreadsheet with text in column A. 
For example

```
A1=MY TEXT1
A2=MY TEXT2
A3=MY TEXT3
A4=MY TEXT4
A5=MY TEXT5
```

I want to add an apostrophe to the front and back of the text
Result to be:

```
B1='MY TEXT1'
B2='MY TEXT2'
B3='MY TEXT3'
B4='MY TEXT4'
B5='MY TEXT5'
```

It seems like a straight forward thing to do.  Any one know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
="'" & A1 & "'"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
=CONCATENATE("'";A1;"'")
```

Comment: @Bart...I tried that and got "The Formula you typed contains and error".  Any ideas?

Comment: @Bart....these worked =CONCATENATE("'",A1,",'") =CONCATENATE("'" & A1 & ",'") ="'" & A1 &"'"   Could it be an Excel version thing that the ; didn't work?

Comment: @Mike , is the argument separator for functions in the English version of Excel, but ; is the argument separator in most other language versions